# Unable to dispatch an action in react-redux using typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I am developing a TODO app using react redux typescript. I am unable to dispatch an action. I am new to redux so stuck in it. I am creating an event onclick handleSubmitButton then it is throwing dispatch error. Can someone help me in that ?

AddToDo.tsx

```
const AddToDo: React.FC = () => {
    const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState<string>("");

    const handleSubmitButton = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>)=> {
        e.preventDefault()
        console.log(inputValue, "inputValue");
        dispatch(addTodo(inputValue))
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <form noValidate>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="todoitem">Todo Item:</label>
                    <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Enter Text" value={inputValue} id="todoitem" onChange={handleEditTodoItem} />
                </div>
                <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={handleSubmitButton}>Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}

export default connect()(AddToDo)
```

Below is my action code -

```
export const addTodo = (name: string): AddTodoAction => (
   {
    type: ActionTypes.ADD_TODO,
    payload: {
      todo: {
        id: nextId++,
        name: name,
        done: false
      }
    }
  }
)
```

and Now my reducer code -

```
export function reducer(state: State = initialState, action: Action) {

  switch (action.type) {
    case ActionTypes.ADD_TODO: {

      const todo = action.payload.todo

      return {
        ...state,
        todos: [...state.todos, todo]
      }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason you are getting a "dispatch error" is because `dispatch` is probably `undefined`. This is because you failed to:

```
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
// ...
const dispatch = useDispatch();
```

If using the hooks to hook into redux, you don't need to "connect" anything, nor write `mapDispatchToProps`. Just [`useSelector` and `useDispatch` are enough to hook](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks) into the redux store, which makes for a much friendlier experience.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on not using [Redux hooks](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks).
You are close, but you forgot to import your dispatch in `connect()` using `mapDispatchToProps`. This would look like something like this:

```
import { Dispatch } from 'redux';
import { addToDo } from '../action'; // replace this import with the correct path to your action

    type AddToDoProps = {
       addToDo: (inputValue: string) => void;
    }

    const AddToDo: React.FC<AddToDoProps> = ({ addToDo }) => {
    const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState<string>("");

    const handleSubmitButton = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>)=> {
        e.preventDefault()
        console.log(inputValue, "inputValue");
        addTodo(inputValue)
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <form noValidate>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label htmlFor="todoitem">Todo Item:</label>
                    <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Enter Text" value={inputValue} id="todoitem" onChange={handleEditTodoItem} />
                </div>
                <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={handleSubmitButton}>Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch) => ({
   addToDo: (inputValue: string) => dispatch(addToDo(inputValue))
})

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(AddToDo)
```

Note: You are getting your dispatch method as a prop in your component which means you will have to define this prop in Typescript.

```
type AddToDoProps = {
  addToDo: (inputValue: string) => void;
}
```

Add this type to your component and define your dispatch prop in order to use it:

```
const AddToDo: React.FC<AddToDoProps> = ({ addToDo }) => ...
```

Comment: The [redux hooks](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks) make life much easier now (athough keeping redux dependencies out of your visual components makes for much easier testing, so it's a mixed blessing).

Comment: Oh I just checked the docs and indeed the redux approach with hooks seems to be a lot easier.  I'll leave this answer for people that aren't using hooks. Thanks for letting me know tho!

Comment: I'm still torn on whether or not they are a good idea. This nice thing about this approach is that the visual component is entirely standalone from the connecting HOC. I suppose a similar model can be used with hooks by using a separate component for wiring-up of redux.